# Can an RV exceed the "50% fixed load" rule?

Tags: electrical

Suppose you have an RV.  It has a number of fixed, factory installed onboard loads - lights, heating, hot plate, etc.    It also has some NEMA 5-15 receptacles.

The RV is wired with an "inlet" or a cord, which goes into a receptacle at the home or RV park or campsite.

Normally, if a circuit has receptacles, the fixed loads on that circuit can't be more than 50% of circuit capacity.

**Is that also true for RVs?**   That is to say: Does the presence of a 120V/30A plug/inlet imply that the fixed loads in the RV only draw 15A max?

Answer (score 1):

IMO no. What is plugged in is the load, ie: the RV. The RV itself falls under a different set of codes, and IMO is not in and of itself a fixed load.

To be honest I have no idea how load calculations are done for the internal wiring of an RV. Interesting question though.